# What would be my Configuring File (Web.xml)?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I need  to configure This file i tried to run this file but error was file not found : 404. so what would be the configure file I need  to configure This file i tried to run this file but error was file not found : 404. so what would be the configure file

**LoginService.java**

```js
package com.webService;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.pojo.UserVO;
import com.model.SecurityManager;;

@Path("/WebService")
public class LoginService 
{
    @POST
        @Path("/login")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        public String login(@FormParam("username") String username, @FormParam("password") String password)
        {           
            return getAllUsersList(username, password);
        }

    public String getAllUsersList(String username, String password)
    {
        String userListData=null;
        ArrayList<UserVO> userList = null;
        SecurityManager sm = new  SecurityManager();
        userList =sm.getAllUsersList();

        for(UserVO userVO: userList)
        {
            if(userVO.getUsername().equals(username))
            {
                if(userVO.getPassword().equals(password))
                {
                    return "Logged In User :" + username;
                }
            }   
        }

        return "You Are not a Valid User";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>FirstProject</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>REST</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: It's very hard to grasp your problem. Please re-phrase your introduction and make it clear what you're actually struggling with.

Comment: is my web.xml is right? because when ever m trying to compile the project i get error 404